# Why static block doesn't load in called object?

Tags: java

```
class Super { static String ID = "SUPER_ID"; }

class SubClass extends Super{
  static { System.out.print("In SubClass"); }
}

class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(SubClass.ID);
  }
}
```

Why i have in output

```
SUPER_ID
```

instead of

```
In SubClass
SUPER_ID
```

---

**SubClass** will be loaded in the first call of object. So why `static` init block doesn't execute?
Thanks.

Comment: You are not initializing `SubClass`, you are referring to the `static` field in it (it `extends Super`).

Comment: @MarounMaroun but if i have interface which contains `static` constants my interface load into `JVM` in the first time i called. What the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because during compile time itself, SubClass.ID will be changed to Super.ID by the compiler. 
And like @Kugathasan Abimaran says, inheritance and static are two different things.

Example :

```
public class SampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SubClass.ID);
        System.out.println(SubClass.i);
    }
}

class Super {
    static String ID = "SUPER_ID";
}

class SubClass extends Super {
    static {
        System.out.println("In SubClass");
    }

    static int i;
}

Output :
SUPER_ID
In SubClass // only when accessing a variable of subclass, the class will be initialized.
0
```

Comment: inheritance with static members? Wrong wordings.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran - What I meant to say was - The class is not yet loaded into the JVM and during compilation itself, SubClass.ID will be referenced as Super.ID

Comment: I think a more appropriate term will be 'static fields linking', it is done at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not loaded by class loader because it was not used in your **Test class**, If you want to load it just add the statement `Class.forName("SubClass");` in your test class after that your could be able to see the result as you are expecting. you can also load this class using class loader instead of `Class.forName`.

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class.forName("SubClass");
    //Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("SubClass");
    System.out.println(SubClass.ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to The Java Language Specification:

> A reference to a static field causes initialization of only the class or
>   interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the
>   name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface.

[More info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)